What are all the complex structures on $\mathbb{R}^2$ which live inside $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$?
By "complex structure" I am referring to 2x2 matrices which square to $-\mathrm{Id}_2$. I need to know those with integer entries and determinant equal to 1.
Thank you

The matrices in $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ whose square is $-\mathrm{Id}_2$ are precisely the matrices in $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ with characteristic polynomial $x^2+1$. So these are the matrices in  $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ whose trace is zero. By looking at the corresponding fixed points in the upper half-plane, it is not hard to show that the matrices in question form two conjugacy classes in $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ with representative elements
$$\begin{pmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}\qquad\text{and}\qquad\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{pmatrix}.$$
Added. Mutatis mutandis, the matrices in $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ whose cube is $-\mathrm{Id}_2$ are precisely the matrices in $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ with characteristic polynomial $x^2-x+1$. So these are the matrices in  $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ whose trace is one. By looking at the corresponding fixed points in the upper half-plane, it is not hard to show that the matrices in question form two conjugacy classes in $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ with representative elements
$$\begin{pmatrix}1&-1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}\qquad\text{and}\qquad\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\-1&1\end{pmatrix}.$$

Thank you. As a follow up, can I ask if these conjugacy classes contain infinitely many distinct elements in $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ ? Furthermore, would it be easy to determine all the roots (not just square) of $-\mathrm{Id}_2$ inside $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ ?

@nayreel Yes, both conjugacy classes contain infinitely many elements. The conjugacy class of $\begin{pmatrix}0&-1\1&0\end{pmatrix}$ consists of the integral matrices $\begin{pmatrix}a&b\c&-a\end{pmatrix}$ with $c>0$ and $a^2+bc=-1$. The conjugacy class of $\begin{pmatrix}0&1\-1&0\end{pmatrix}$ consists of the integral matrices $\begin{pmatrix}a&b\c&-a\end{pmatrix}$ with $c<0$ and $a^2+bc=-1$. I continue in the next remark.

@nayreel To your second question: if an element of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ has finite order $n$, then $n\in{1,2,3,4,6}$. These orders do occur in $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$, and the corresponding finite order elements have a simple description as in  the case $n=4$ discussed in my post. In particular, $-\mathrm{Id}_2$ only has square-roots and cube-roots in $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$.

Thank you for your detailed response! Do you have a source I can use? As I am trying to utilize these facts in a paper without proving them myself. Also, for the cubic roots, is there a nice description like there is for square roots? i.e. Can I classify cubic roots similarly to how you classified the square roots?

@nayreel See my added section. Again, both conjugacy classes contain infinitely many elements. The conjugacy class of $\begin{pmatrix}1&-1\1&0\end{pmatrix}$ consists of the integral matrices $\begin{pmatrix}a&b\c&1-a\end{pmatrix}$ with $c>0$ and $a^2-a+bc=-1$. The conjugacy class of $\begin{pmatrix}0&1\-1&1\end{pmatrix}$ consists of the integral matrices $\begin{pmatrix}a&b\c&1-a\end{pmatrix}$ with $c<0$ and $a^2-a+bc=-1$. I continue in the next remark.

@nayreel I don't know a good reference for all this, I proved the above when I needed it. At any rate, many books discuss the action of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ on the upper half-plane, and how this gives rise to the elliptic/parabolic/hyperbolic classification of elements of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$. This is very standard material. I continue in the next remark.

@nayreel I gave you a detailed description of the order $4$ and order $6$ elliptic elements of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$, which is straightforward to deduce from the mentioned standard material. You can quote this MO entry, by the way, and the referee will have no problem with it (I think).

thank you for this. I might have to refer to one of these books which discuss the action of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ on the upper half plane. I am not very knowledgeable in linear algebra, could you tell me what some of those books are (possibly with reference to a chapter/chapters which discuss this specific classification into elliptic/parabolic/hyperbolic elements) ? Thank you very much for your continued help.

@nayreel Try Sections 2.1-2.2 in Iwaniec: Topics in classical automorphic forms. Or simply read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SL2(R)

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@nayreel I don't have time for chatting, and this will be my last comment here. You can verify my claims by proving the following. Let $\Gamma=\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$, and let $H$ be the upper half-plane. Let $F$ be the closure of the standard fundamental domain of $\Gamma$ acting on $H$ (see Theorem 1.2 in Iwaniec's book). Each elliptic element $\gamma\in\Gamma$ has a $\Gamma$-conjugate $\begin{pmatrix}a&b\c&d\end{pmatrix}\in\Gamma$ whose fixed point $z$ lies in $F$. By expressing $z$ in terms of the integer entries $a,b,c,d$ and using also $|a+d|<2$, verify that $|a|,|b|,|c|,|d|\leq 1$.

Thank you. I know you said this is your last comment but you said $|a|$, $|b|$, $|c|$, $|d|\leq 1$, shouldn't this imply that there are at most 3^4 possibilities for the matrix? I thought there were an infinite amount of elliptic elements of order 4 and 6?

@nayreel The finitely many $\begin{pmatrix}a&b\c&d\end{pmatrix}\in\Gamma$ that you end up with represent all $\Gamma$-conjugacy classes of elliptic elements of $\Gamma\setminus{\pm\mathrm{Id}_2}$, and their orders are $4$ or $6$. So there are finitely many such classes (in fact there are six classes, two for trace $0$, two for trace $1$, and two for trace $-1$). Please read my previous comment more carefully: each elliptic element $\gamma\in\Gamma$ has a $\Gamma$-conjugate etc.

Oh ok, but earlier you said there were 4 conjugacy classes (two for order 4 elements, two for order 6 elements). What are the remaining two?

@nayreel There are two conjugacy classes of order $4$ elements, two conjugacy classes of order $6$ elements, and two conjugacy classes of order $3$ elements. The order $3$ elements are the squares of the order $6$ elements, so they are represented by $$\begin{pmatrix}0&-1\1&-1\end{pmatrix}\qquad\text{and}\qquad\begin{pmatrix}-1&1\-1&0\end{pmatrix}.$$ And there is also $-\mathrm{Id}_2$ of order $2$ and $\mathrm{Id}_2$ or order $1$. I should really stop here.

Thank you sincerely for your extended help today. I won't ask anything else.

@nayreel Great. I updated my last comment with explicit representatives for the order $3$ elements. I should add that the elements $\pm\mathrm{Id}_2$ of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ are special, and they are not considered elliptic/parabolic/hyperbolic; they determine the identity motion on $H$. Iwaniec makes this clear as well.
